# Flatten an iterator of iterators in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, iterator

Flatten an iterator of iterators in Java. If the input is [ [1,2], [3,[4,5]], 6], it should return [1,2,3,4,5,6]. Implement hasNext() and next(). Be careful when the inner iterator or list is empty.
I don't think my code works for multiple levels of inner lists.

```java
public class FlattenList {
    int index = 0;  // keep an index to indicate where the current accessed element is
    List<Integer> flattenedList = new ArrayList<>();    // flattenedList
    public FlattenList(List<List<Integer>> lists){  
        for(List<Integer> list : lists){    // add all inner list to our underlying list.
            flattenedList.addAll(list);
        }
    }
    public boolean hasNext(){   // check if the index has exceeded the list size
        return flattenedList.size() > index? true : false; 
    }
    public Integer next(){  // return the next element, and increment the index
        Integer result = flattenedList.get(index);
        index++;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your function takes a List of Lists (of Integers), not an Iterator of Iterators (of a generic type) (the code of which Chris' answer should help you with).

Answer (score 2):

So basically this is like writing a depth first traversal of a tree.  Leaf nodes of this tree are numbers, all interior nodes are modeled as Iterators. Here is some pseudo code:

```
void flatten(Iterator<Object> iterator, List<Integer> flattenedList) {
    for (Object o : iterator)  {
        if (o instanceof Iterator) {
          flatten((Iterator) o, flattenedList);
        } else {
          flattenedList.add((Integer) o);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'll start it for you:

```
public <T> Iterator<T> flatten(final Iterator<Iterator<T>> iterators) {
    if (iterators == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("iterators can't be null");
    }

    return new Iterator<>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented: hasNext");
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented: next");
        }
    };
}
```

Now you just do that pesky brainwork and you'll be done.

**EDIT**

If you're not used to that syntax, here's a slightly easier one:

```
public <T> Iterator<T> flatten(final Iterator<Iterator<T>> iterators) {
    return new MyFlatteningIterator<>(iterators);
}

public class MyFlatteningIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final Iterator<Iterator<T>> iterators;

    public MyFlatteningIterator(final Iterator<Iterator<T>> iterators) {
        if (iterators == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("iterators can't be null");
        }
        this.iterators = iterators;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented: hasNext");
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented: next");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Now that I am thinking about it, since given a list which can can contain elements as well as lists and output is an iterator to flatten a nested list. Could I first flatten the nested list in constructor and store it in a plain list. Subsequently, the next() and hasNext() work off of the plain list with a simple counter that points to where the current element is being fetched. To flatten a list, we use composite pattern algorithm like this http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Java. How do you think of this approach?

Comment: @user3216886 The instructions clearly say "Iterator" not "List", so don't restrict yourself to Lists. Also, ask yourself about memory: if I have 1 million iterators that each iterate over 1 million items each, is it really all that practical to pre-flatten the entire collection? Would that exhaust the memory? Is there a less memory-intense way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You should not treat this as a list, rather as Jon stated this is more suitable when you are talking about trees. If you infect looking for a solution to get a flatted iterator of list of lists (something that looks like [[1],[1,2,3],[8,9]]) then I think that the following solution will work better

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class FlattedIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private Iterator<T>[] iteratorsArray;

    public FlattedIterator(Collection<T>[] items) {
        this.iteratorsArray = new Iterator[items.length];

        for(int index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            this.iteratorsArray[index] = items[index].iterator();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        boolean hasNext = false;

        for(int index = 0; index < this.iteratorsArray.length; index++) {
            hasNext |= this.iteratorsArray[index].hasNext();
        }

        return hasNext;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        int index = 0;

        while(index < this.iteratorsArray.length && !this.iteratorsArray[index].hasNext()) {
            index++;
        }

        if(index >= this.iteratorsArray.length ) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Reached end of iterator");
        }

        return this.iteratorsArray[index].next();
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that the reason that I think this solution will work better is due to the fact that in your solution you initialized flattenedList by adding all the data from the given lists meaning that if in some point of the program one of those lists will received more data **after** you initialized FlattenList then the new data wont appear while you read the iterator.